# How can I upgrade iOS 6 beta to iOS6 public release

Tags: ios6

I have the iOS6 beta installed on my iPhone and I can't figure out how to upgrade to the newest public release. This is my first time running the beta version but I can't find any info on upgrading.

Going into General>Software Update says I'm up to date. Do I have to restore my iOS5 image and the re-upgrade?

Comment: Which beta are you using? If you're using the GM seed from last week, you may actually be up to date.

Comment: I don't remember updating last week (time is flying!)... I think I have iOS beta 4. One thing, I don't have the panoramic feature under the camera (using a 4s), and the passbook has a landing page still.

Comment: Just pulled up the version info, it's 10A5376e which comes up as beta4 on google. What's weird is it will says checking for updates, spin and sat up to date.

Comment: You cannot upgrade OTA. You need to download the GM from the iOS Dev Center again, which is identical to the public release and eligible for updating to iOS 6.0.1 later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download the latest IPSW from the developer site, and use iTunes. Shift-click/Option-click on the Update button and point it to the IPSW. It will take a short time upgrade, and you're done.

Comment: Perfect!, I didn't realize you could force an update.... I almost did a force restore.

Comment: I finished doing this, can confirm that it worked perfectly.  No issues losing apps etc. as far as I can tell (which happened when I first updated from iOS5 to iOS6).  I did a backup just in case before I updated though.  Probably a good idea in most cases.

Camera now has panorama, passbook links properly.  Thanks for the help!